# After Scroll Into View How can I get an element's new absolute coordinates in Selenium Java?

Tags: java, selenium

Is there a way to return the new absolute co-ordinates of an off-screen element after it has scrolled into view?

I've tried refreshing the element by extracting it's xPath

```java
String xPath = generateXpath(this.currentElement, "");
this.currentElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath));
```

Here is my current code:

```java
//Output initial X, Y coordinates
System.out.println ("X: "+  String.valueOf(this.currentElement.getAttribute("offsetTop")));
System.out.println ("Y: "+ String.valueOf(this.currentElement.getAttribute("offsetLeft")));

//X: 495
//Y: 3109

//Scroll object into view at the bottom of the page
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false);", this.currentElement);
this.currentElement.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
this.currentElement.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);


//Output new absolute X, Y coordinates
System.out.println ("X: "+  String.valueOf(this.currentElement.getAttribute("offsetTop")));
System.out.println ("Y: "+ String.valueOf(this.currentElement.getAttribute("offsetLeft")));

//Same as original coordinates
//X: 495
//Y: 3109
```

Expected results is the new absolute screen position

X: 495
Y: 997

Comment: Do you want absolute coordinates, or coordinates relative to the browser viewport?

Comment: Absolute coordinates do not change when scrolling the page (hence the word "absolute").

Comment: I also tried this:


Point point = this.currentElement.getLocation();

System.out.println ("Point X: "+ point.getX());
System.out.println ("Point X: "+ point.x);
System.out.println ("Point Y: "+ point.getY());
System.out.println ("Point Y: "+ point.y);

Comment: Relative to the browser viewport would work, although calculating the actual physical screen co-ordinates would be best.

Comment: This is what I'm confused about. Scrolling an element into view should **not** change its absolute coordinates. It should change its `scrollTop`, for instance, but the x,y coordinates from the top-left corner of the screen should remain unchanged.

Comment: What is your usecase exactly? Why do you want to _get the element's new absolute coordinates after ScrollIntoView_ ?

Comment: Greg I tried this:

System.out.println ("X: "+ String.valueOf(this.currentElement.getAttribute("scrollTop")));
System.out.println ("Y: "+ String.valueOf(this.currentElement.getAttribute("scrollLeft")));

and it returned X:0, Y:0

Comment: Sure @DebanjanB - I'm experimenting with porting an advanced object model design that I engineered in UFT to much success 11 years ago, and also into Selenium last year.

Yesterday I found none of the three approaches to click an element - .Click, executeScript, sendkeys(Keys.ENTER) - reliably worked if the object was displayed off screen. The only way these approaches worked was if I had first clicked an onscreen link that scrolled the button element into view. So I'm looking to implement an old school solution: Scroll and execute a click at the element's x+10, y+10 screen location.

Comment: Here is the use case:
Navigate to my sandbox  www.CandyMapper.com  1) click the onscreen  'Get In Touch' button to scroll the 'Send' button into view. 2) Click the 'Send' button. 3) Verify the expected result: an error message regarding a "valid email address" appears.  Then try it again, but without clicking the 'Get In Touch' button.  1) Click the off screen 'Send' element. 2) Verify the expected message appears. In my tests the click executes without error, but the error message does not appear. If this was UFT the "abs_x" and "abs_y" properties return the updated screen coordinates.

Comment: @DarkArtsWizard As per the steps you mentioned, through Selenium the first usecase would be a 4 line code and the second usecase would be a 3 line code. I havn't worked with UFT but Selenium is much more user action oriented and easier to mock user actions. I still don't see why you need the coordinates.

Comment: you shouldn't need a scroll to click that button.  The driver will scroll if necessary: https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver1/#element-click  The offsets will return zero if there is no style association with the item.  Might want to try calling getClientRects or getBoundingClientRect on the element.  Though I don't really see why you expect the location to change.

Comment: Well the difference between theory and reality is striking.

Comment: Here's the solution which I got from a friend who never once asked me "Why would you ever want to do this?" He simply directed me to the right solution.

Comment: double abs_y = (double) js.executeScript("return arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect().top; ", currentElement);

Answer (score 0):

First move the browser to the physical 0, 0 location on the desktop. Note: in some cases Selenium will place the browser a few pixels to the right of 0, 0. Thus the .setPosition may need to be offset for accuracy.

```
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(-5,0)); //offset
```

Next use JavaScript to return the getBoundingClientRect().left and getBoundingClientRect().top values to return the x and y co-ordinates. Again offsets will need to be used for accuracy.

```
public static int getAbsY(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) {

     double y = (double) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
            "return arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect().top", element);
    return (int) y + 25;  //Offset

}


public static int getAbsX(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) {

    double x = (double) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
            "return arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect().left", element);
    return (int) x + 12;  //Offset

}
```

Finally use the Robot class to move the mouse to the element location to ensure location accuracy.

```
public static void moveMouseTo(WebDriver driver, WebElement element){

    int x =  getAbsX(driver, element);
    int y =  getAbsY(driver, element);

    Robot robot = null;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
    }

    robot.mouseMove(x, y);

}


moveMouseTo(element);
```

As for why one would want to do this: Professional level SDETs often will create element descriptions on the fly in their test automation frameworks. This will visually ensure the correct element has been located.